# Curl POST - 411 Length Required

Tags: php, lighttpd, curl

We have a RestFUL API we build in PHP. If we make the request:

```
curl -u api-key:api-passphrase https://api.domain.com/v1/product -X POST
```

We get back:

```
411 - Length Required
```

Though if we simply add `-d ""` onto the request it works and no 411 error. Is there a way to not require adding -d to the curl command?

We are using lighttpd web server, and believe its lighttpd NOT php who is returning the 411 error.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You are correct -- lighttpd doesn't support POST requests with an empty message body without a 'Content-Length' header set to zero, and CURL sends such a request. There's argument back and forth about who's right, but in my opinion, lighttpd is broken. A POST with no Content-Length and no Transfer-Encoding is perfectly legal and has no message body.

Adding `-d ""` causes CURL to send a `Content-Length: 0` header, which resolves the problem.

You could modify lighttp. Find the code that issues the 411 error and instead set the content length to zero.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, so there is no flag to pass to curl  besides `-d ""` or a config lighttpd directive to set? `-d ""` just looks like a hack.

Comment: It is a hack. If you want to fix the problem for real, you'd have to modify lighttpd. You can instead use `-d @/dev/null` if you think that looks better. You can also use `-H "Content-Length: 0"`. (I tested both of these, they work.)